# Filter dataframe on second row using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, isin

I have a dataframe that needs to be kept in the structure below.

```
df
  One       two   three          
  date      apple  banana
2019-12-20   0      4
2020-01-03   10     5
```

Is there a way to keep only columns where the second row is contained within the list? I'm only familiar with doing this for columns

```
fruits= ["date", "apple"]
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(fruits)
```

Expected Output

```
   One       two          
  date      apple  
2019-12-20   0      
2020-01-03   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.isin` and use the `level` argument to specify the level of the multiindex.

if you don't have a multiindex set, you can set it on your read.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep='\s+',header=[0,1])

df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(fruits,level=1)]

print(df)
         One   two
         date apple
2  2019-12-20     0
3  2020-01-03    10
```

---

```
df.columns.isin(fruits,level=1)
array([ True,  True, False])
```

Comment: It's not a multi index unfortunately. I get the data frame from a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

As your dataframe is not in multi-index columns and you want to filter columns by row 0 values, you can use `.isin()` on the first row with `iloc[0]`:

```
df.loc[:, df.iloc[0].isin(fruits)]
```

Result:

```
          One    two
0        date  apple
1  2019-12-20      0
2  2020-01-03     10
```